# Finding a sum of cells given address range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a google sheet formula

[Click here to make a copy of sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h1XeKgeoR9tTU9UWILjLNyG4_fM4f93HkTNquwtP__Q/copy)

I have a data in table from B column to H column
Data runs from left to right only in B through H
Given a starting address of the cell and given a ending address of the cell
(in the image you see H1 and H2 columns)

I want to find the sum of all cells from the start to end address with respect from B through H

**When yellow value dates are changed the sum should be reflected accordingly.**

[image]

My results are incorrect since it needs to find the sum spanning the cells from B to H column

I have tried with

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(H1&":"&H2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=let(cols,tocol(B5:H,1),start,(D1-1)*7+F1,end,(D2-1)*7+F2,sum(chooserows(cols,sequence(end-start+1,1,start))))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76261933/finding-a-sum-of-cells-given-address-range-in-another-tab-of-google-sheet ?

Answer (score 3):

`OFFSET()` may work with few other functions. Try-

```
=LET(
UB,REGEXEXTRACT(H2,"\d+"),
LB,REGEXEXTRACT(H1,"\d+"),
x,SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H1),,,UB-LB,7)),
y,SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H1),UB-LB,,1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(H2))-COLUMN(INDIRECT(H1))+1)),
x+y)
```

[image]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/04EqCy3WOw27 this formula doesnt work when date is changed

Answer (score 2):

***Updated answer:***

```
=sum(filter(tocol(B5:index(H5:H,D2)),isbetween(--tocol(sequence(D2)&sequence(1,7)),--(D1&F1),--(D2&F2))))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76261933/finding-a-sum-of-cells-given-address-range-in-another-tab-of-google-sheet