# Finding a sum of cells given address range in another tab of google sheet file using importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a google sheet formula

A variation of solution mentioned in [Finding a sum of cells given address range in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259868/finding-a-sum-of-cells-given-address-range-in-google-sheets)
This question is to about referencing data from some other google sheet file and computing the total.

[Click here to make a copy of data sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10q1hgvP8FgdTHkwH4y1ls5Tv1di6XYgyblq4gm_PK-I/edit#gid=103277278/copy)

[Click here to make a copy of report sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xiIHPwQzNA8dEzSbgJU1xcQA6bGyED6cZOG3udlx02I/copy)

[image]

I have a data in Employee tables from B column to H column

Data runs from left to right only in B through H

Given a starting address of the cell and given a ending address of the cell

(in the image you see H1 and H2 columns)

I want to find the sum of all cells from the start to end address with respect from B through H

**When yellow value dates are changed the sum should be reflected accordingly based on the data of the Empoyee table.**

[image]

My results are incorrect since it needs to find the sum spanning the cells from B to H column

I have tried with

```
=let(cols,tocol(
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10q1hgvP8FgdTHkwH4y1ls5Tv1di6XYgyblq4gm_PK-I/edit#gid=103277278","'Employee'!B5:H")
,1),start,((WEEKNUM(D2))-1)*7+(WEEKDAY(D2,2)),end,((WEEKNUM(D3))-1)*7+(WEEKDAY(D3,2)),sum(chooserows(cols,sequence(end-start+1,1,start))))
```

**Please note that Employee sheets are READONLY since they are being fetched from some other external spreadsheets using import formula**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,importrange("10q1hgvP8FgdTHkwH4y1ls5Tv1di6XYgyblq4gm_PK-I",A6&"!B5:H"),
     start_,weeknum(D$2),end_,weeknum(D$3),
     sum(filter(tocol(chooserows(Σ,sequence(end_))),isbetween(--tocol(sequence(end_)&sequence(1,7)),--(start_&weekday(D$2,2)),--(end_&weekday(D$3,2))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the error was just that 'Employee' needed to be changed to 'Employee1' etc. Interesting use of Isbetween, I hadn't come across that before.